# How to scrape and infinity scrolling page?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I was trying to **scrape** the men's coats and jackets category in next.co.uk and I realized that the page has the infinity scrolling page

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import NextItem

class NewoneSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'newOne'
    allowed_domains = ['www.next.co.uk']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.next.co.uk/shop/gender-newbornboys-gender-newbornunisex-gender-olderboys-gender-youngerboys-productaffiliation-coatsandjackets-0'
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = NextItem();
        global productCategory
        global productSubCategory
        products = response.css('.Details')
        currentUrl = response.request.url

        for product in products:
            productCategory = 'Furniture'
            productSubCategory = 'living Room'
            productCountry = 'uk'
            productSeller = 'John Lewis'
            productLink = product.css('.TitleText::attr(href)').extract_first()
            productTitle = product.css('.Desc::text').extract_first()
            productImage = product.css('.Image img::attr(src)').extract_first()
            productSalePrice = product.css('.Price a::text').extract_first()

            items['productCategory'] = productCategory
            items['productSubCategory'] = productSubCategory
            items['productCountry'] = productCountry
            items['productSeller'] = productSeller
            items['productLink'] = productLink
            items['productTitle'] = productTitle
            items['productImage'] = productImage
            items['productSalePrice'] = productSalePrice

            yield items
```

I was able to scrape 28 items and I can see more than that on on the website which has infinite scrolling implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you scroll down the page sends XHR call to the server and asks for more data.
Example:

```
https://www.next.co.uk/shop/gender-newbornboys-gender-newbornunisex-gender-olderboys-gender-youngerboys-productaffiliation-coatsandjackets/isort-score-minprice-0-maxprice-30000-srt-24
```

Each request is almost the same but the last element in the url is growing up by 24:

- srt-24
- srt-48
- srt-72

Now that you know how the "infinity" works, you can try and simulate it with code.

Example:

```
import requests

URL_TEMPLATE = 'https://www.next.co.uk/shop/gender-newbornboys-gender-newbornunisex-gender-olderboys-gender-youngerboys-productaffiliation-coatsandjackets/isort-score-minprice-0-maxprice-30000-srt-{}'

for step in range(24, 240, 24):
    r = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE.format(step))
    if r.status_code == 200:
        # TODO We have the data - lets parse it
        pass
```

Comment: still scraping the normal amount of items

Comment: @fafoworatobi I am not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: it start from page two items and scrape only page two items

Comment: @fafoworatobi Did you look at my example code? Can you share your updated code?

Comment: it's working
i saw your example right now
i have been able to scrape 216 items from that category

Comment: wat if i have more than one link i want to scrape how would the code look like

Answer (score 0):

if i have two links i want to scrape from like
https://www.next.co.uk/shop/gender-newbornboys-gender-newbornunisex-gender-olderboys-gender-youngerboys-productaffiliation-coatsandjackets-0
and
https://www2.next.co.uk/shop/gender-men-productaffiliation-coatsandjackets-0
how would the code be like